# Spring RestTemplate conflicts with javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword and javax.net.ssl.trustStore

Tags: sockets, ssl, certificate, spring-rest

We are working on a project which connects to external server via `Socket` the connection type is `ssl`.
The certificate is self signed and the project code sets `System Property` to by pass the certificate validation by some thing like this:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", .....);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ....);
```

We are trying to extend the project and use `Spring RestTemplate`. But some strange thing happens !

When we create and inject a new `RestTemplate` object, the old codes stop working and I get `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

The codes have nothing in common nor in source neither in the objects...

What is happening ? Does the `Spring RestTemplate` change or effects system properties ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that default Apache `HttpComponent` cause the error. And I don't know why !!

I switched to `OKHttp3`. And the old codes keep working again.

Here is a sample code:

As it was self signed certificate I add them from store to OkkHttp `HandshakeCertificates`

```
        List<X509Certificate> certificates = getCertificatesFromTrustStore();
        
        Builder certificateBuilder =  new HandshakeCertificates.Builder();        
        for (X509Certificate x509Certificate : certificates) {
            certificateBuilder.addTrustedCertificate(x509Certificate);
        }
        HandshakeCertificates handshakeCertificates =  certificateBuilder.build();

        ConnectionPool okHttpConnectionPool = new ConnectionPool(MAX_IDLE_CONNETION, KEEP_ALIVE_DURATION, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .hostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())       
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
                    .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .sslSocketFactory(handshakeCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), handshakeCertificates.trustManager())
                    .connectionPool(okHttpConnectionPool)
                    .build();
            
        ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =  new OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory(okHttpClient);
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
                new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(
                        clientHttpRequestFactory
                ));    

        //Set error handler
        MyRestTemplateResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new MyRestTemplateResponseErrorHandler();
        errorHandler.setMessageConverters(restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        
        return restTemplate;
    }

    private List<X509Certificate> getCertificatesFromTrustStore() throws KeyStoreException, IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, FileNotFoundException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        truststore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStorePath), keystorePass.toCharArray());
        
        Set<TrustAnchor> trustAnchors = new PKIXParameters(truststore).getTrustAnchors();
        LOG.debug("{} certificates found in {} which will be used", trustAnchors.size(), trustStorePath);
        
        List<X509Certificate> certificates = trustAnchors.stream()
                  .map(TrustAnchor::getTrustedCert)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return certificates;
    }
```